# GeoFire with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, geofire

I plan to use GeoFire to filter my firebase data based on location. Not sure how to get started with this because I just started developing. I have a pic and a caption etc that I create in one Class with:

```
    @IBAction func shareDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
            if let image = image, let caption = textView.text {
                let newMedia = Media(type: "image", caption: caption, createdBy: user, image: image)
                    newMedia.save(completion: { (error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            self.alert(title: "Oops!", message: error.localizedDescription, buttonTitle: "OK")
                        } else {
                            self.user.share(newMedia: newMedia)
```

in a separate "User" class (MVC) I save it into Firebase with

```
    func share(newMedia: Media) {
            DatabaseReference.users(uid: uid).reference().child("media").childByAutoId().setValue(newMedia.uid)
        }
```

Where do I instantiate the GeoFire reference? Do I have to use Core Location to get my own Lat and Lon? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding **GeoFire**

Install with pods
`pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'`

Then import to project `import GeoFire`

Create a reference to it using

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference()
let geoRef = GeoFire(firebaseRef: rootRef.child("user_locations"))
```

To get the current user location you can use **Location manager** via cocoa pods: https://github.com/varshylmobile/LocationManager

I am guessing you want the media saved on the database to have a location. You then use GeoFire to save the location using `GeoFire.setlocation`
Call this when you save your post to the database, GeoFire handles the database structure of adding locations using your post ID.

*an example:*

```
geoFire!.setLocation(myLocation, forKey: userID) { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            debugPrint("An error occured: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Saved location successfully!")
        }
    }
```

You then query the database of locations using `CircleQuery`
You can give a radius of how far you want to query the database within from a given location *(user location)*

*an example:*

```
let query = geoRef.query(at: userLocation, withRadius: 1000)

query?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in
    guard let key = key else { return }
    print("Key: " + key + "entered the search radius.")
})
```

A really good tutorial that I used was:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wr19iKENC-k&t=600s

Look on their channel and query `GeoFire` for other videos that might help you further.